# xmlstarlet: filter out element with attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

How to filter out elements of certain type which to not have an attribute with a magic value and retain the rest of the document? All this using `xmlstarlet`?

What I have to far is:

```
cat << EOF > database.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<database>

    <some name="A" />
    <some name="B" />
    <some name="C" />
    <text>this is some text to be applied...</text>
    <project>
        <test deeper="structure"/>
    </project>

</database>
EOF
```

and

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "*" -c "*[not(self::some[@name != 'A'])]" database.xml
```

yields

```
<some name="A"/><text>this is some text to be applied...</text><project>
        <test deeper="structure"/>
    </project>
```

But this hides my precious `<database>` `tag`. Besides the *indentation*, which is not a problem... And doesn't work when `<some>` are not a direct descendant of `<database>`, childs of `<project>` for example.

What I want to get is the database as it is, but all `<some>` removed *except* the one named `A`:

```
<database>

    <some name="A" />


    <text>this is some text to be applied...</text>
    <project>
        <test deeper="structure"/>
    </project>

</database>
```

Greetings

Comment: what exactly you want to return? it's not clear from question.

Comment: xpath like *//database/*" may work. post details for `<some> is not direct descendant of <database>...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, xmlstarlet's `sel` doesn't support `apply-templates`, but you can use the `ed` command for this:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '/database//some[@name != "A"]' input.xml
```

Comment: while hacking and learning xslt i got blind... woa man, this is so simple... stupid me... thanks!

Comment: In my case '' made the work. The update command was not working in this form:
`xmlstarlet edit -P -L --update /_:bpm-platform/_:process-engine/_:properties/_:property[@name='jobExecutorActivate'] --value true 
 /camunda/conf/bpm-platform.xml.test`
until I changed it to:
`xmlstarlet edit -P -L --update '/_:bpm-platform/_:process-engine/_:properties/_:property[@name="jobExecutorActivate"]' --value true /camunda/conf/bpm-platform.xml.test`

Answer (score 1):

Write an XSLT stylesheet doing

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="some[@name != 'A']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then call `xmlstarlet` to apply that stylesheet to your input XML: `xmlstarlet tr sheet.xsl input.xml`.

Comment: Ok, great: this gives the result I need... But it would be nice to make this work on the command line...

Comment: while this works splendidly, my requirement was to do this directly from the command line (think Makefile). So accepting the other response as valid, sorry ;-)