# How to partially pretty print XML files from the command line?

Tags: xml, shell, formatting, xmlstarlet, xmllint

I'm writing a unix shell script where I need to pretty print XML files,
but the catch is that there are portions of them that I may not touch.
Namely, they're Apache Jelly scripts, which are contained within the XML
files I need to pretty print. So I need to convert this

```
<proc source="customer"><scriptParam value="_user"/><scriptText><jelly:script>

  <jelly:log level="info">
    this text needs
      to keep its indent level
        and this is none of my business
  </jelly:log>

  <!-- get date -->
  <sql:query var="rs"><![CDATA[
    select sysdate
    from dual
  ]]></sql:query>

</jelly:script>
</scriptText></proc>
```

Into this

```
<proc source="customer">
  <scriptParam value="_user"/>
  <scriptText>
<jelly:script>

  <jelly:log level="info">
    this text needs
      to keep its indent level
        and this is none of my business
  </jelly:log>

  <!-- get date -->
  <sql:query var="rs"><![CDATA[
    select sysdate
    from dual
  ]]></sql:query>

</jelly:script>
  </scriptText>
</proc>
```

Notice that the only change to the `jelly:script` element is newline
before it.

I couldn't find any option in `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet` to ignore a
certain element. Is there any tool that can help me achieve this? I'm on
Linux, if it matters.

Comment: "but the catch is that there are portions of them that I may not touch." - I think this disqualifies `xmlstarlet`, `xmllint`, and probably most XML parser based tools. Otherwise I would have [suggested `xmlstarlet ed`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33292292/319698).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When requirement is that **inside** element jelly:script no spaces may change, then you can use `xml_pp` (on linux installed with the perl package `perl-XML-Twig`.  The option `-p some-element` can be used to preserve all whitespace inside those elements:

```
xml_pp -p jelly:script  thefile.xml
```

That will create this:

```
<proc source="customer">
  <scriptParam value="_user"/>
  <scriptText>
    <jelly:script>

  <jelly:log level="info">
    this text needs
      to keep its indent level
        and this is none of my business
  </jelly:log>

  <!-- get date -->
  <sql:query var="rs"><![CDATA[
    select sysdate
    from dual
  ]]></sql:query>

</jelly:script>
  </scriptText>
</proc>
```

As you can see the start element `<jelly:script>` is also indented, because added spaces are still outside the element.

If that is also forbidden, then you must choose one level higher (`scriptText`), or maybe pipe it to a command that remove those spaces again:

```
xml_pp -p jelly:script thefile.xml | perl -pe 's/^\s*(<jelly:script>)/$1/'
```